# Remove column with zero sum of matrix in js

Tags: javascript, algorithm, matrix

I have a matrix

```
data= [
       [{id:1, value:0},{id:2, value:3},{id:3, value:0},{id:4, value:5}],
       [{id:1, value:7},{id:2, value:4},{id:3, value:0},{id:4, value:9}],
      ];
```

I want to remove those objects(here) having value = 0 at the same position
or to be simple remove a column with sum zero.

Output:

```
data= [
       [{id:1, value:0},{id:2, value:3},{id:4, value:5}],
       [{id:1, value:7},{id:2, value:4},{id:4, value:9}],
      ];
```

Guide me with a performance based approach for very big matrices.

Comment: I would try using [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if a column has other values than zero. Fehn filter out the columns with without some relevant values

```js
var data = [[{ id: 1, value: 0 }, { id: 2, value: 3 }, { id: 3, value: 0 }, { id: 4, value: 5 }], [{ id: 1, value: 7 }, { id: 2, value: 4 }, { id: 3, value: 0 }, { id: 4, value: 9  }]],
    hasValues = data.reduce((r, a) => a.map(({ value }, i) => r[i] || value), []),
    result = data.map(a => a.filter((_, i) => hasValues[i]));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @VPR, please use this version, because it prevents to miuse some sums like zero with relevant values like `-2` and `2`. theactual version has only a look to truthy values.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Array.filter` to filter the desired data. Since your data is 2D array I am using `Array.map` to return new 2D array based on the output of `.filter`

```js
const data= [
       [{id:1, value:8},{id:2, value:3},{id:3, value:0},{id:4, value:5}],
       [{id:1, value:7},{id:2, value:4},{id:3, value:0},{id:4, value:9}],
]

const updatedData = data.map(row => (
  row.filter(column => column.value)
))

console.log(updatedData)
```

Comment: But this would remove any object with value zero. Not just entire column try the same with data = [ [ {id:1, value:0}.... rest same ]];
**Edited the question for clarity.